# SQL Query Prestashop: how to filter combinations?

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.7

i've managed to write an SQL Query on prestashop to export products and combinations with attributes from my ecommerce. Now i would like to filter results, to get only the cheapest combination for every product.

For example, i got this table with 2 products and 3 possible combination for each:

product-price
A          22€
A          44€
A          100€
B          15€
B          30€
B          45€

I would like to know if there's a way with SQL query, using WHERE command or any other, to filter combinations within a product, giving only the cheapest one as result.

So the result of the query SQL would be:

product   -price
A         22€
B         15€

Is it possible please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your SQL so far, so that the community is able to build on that to help you. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a group by or CTE

Answer (score 0):

A simple `GROUP BY` query should work:

```
SELECT product, MIN(price) AS min_price
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY product;
```

**Edit:**

If your price data is in fact text, with a Euro symbol occurring at the end of each price string, then you'll have to remove it, and cast to integer before taking the min:

```
SELECT
    product,
    MIN(CAST(LEFT(price, CHAR_LENGTH(price) - 1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS min_price
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY product;
```

### Demo

But, it would be best to not store currency symbols and numeric price data together in the same column.  Instead, you could add a number column which would maintain to what currency a price corresponds.  Then, you would only need to use my first query to get the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple aggregation query?

```
select product, min(price) as cheapest_price
from mytable
group by product;
```

This will give you the lowest value of price for each value of product.

Comment: Thanks to all i solved the problem. Aggregation query did it!